# referencias relativas y forzar ramas combinadas para evitar un rebase

Tags: git, ramas-git, git-rebase

Estado inicial:

[image: estado inicial]

El objetivo es llegar a esto:

[image: objetivo]

## Intentos

```
$ git checkout -b ref C6

$ git checkout master

$ git rebase ref

$ git branch -f master master~2

$ git checkout C1

$ git branch -f bugFix HEAD^
```

[image: vista gráfica de la solución]

Obtengo:

> Resolviste el nivel en 6 comandos; nuestra mejor solución usa 3.

### Segundo intento

```
git checkout C6
git branch -f master HEAD
git checkout C1
git branch -f bugFix HEAD^
```

### tercer intento

```
$ git branch -f bugFix HEAD^^
$ git checkout C6
$ git branch -f master HEAD
$ git checkout C1
```

¿Existe una forma de hacerlo con referenias relativas y forzando un rebase de manera que no tenga que usas un branch auxiliar y así me ahorre pasos para llegar hasta los 3 que es la solución óptima?

Answer (score 0):

Hallé una solución:

```
$ git branch -f master C6
$ git branch -f bugFix HEAD~2
$ git checkout C1
```

Se puede hacer force de un branch a un commit específico, es por eso que

```
git branch -f master C6
```

Nos ahorra pasos.